# Add exif creation time with correct timezone (TZD) to filename

Tags: applescript, command-line, automator, exif

Hi i have a problem renaming a lot of photo and images files. I use a shellscript in automator to rename them by EXIF date and time. But the time is given by UTC and im living in europe with +0100 in vinter and +0200 in the summer.
Example: a picture from 2020-06-30 taken at 22:22:30
is named    "**2020-06-30 20/22/30 IMG_0001.jpg**"
instead of. "**2020-06-30 22/22/30 IMG_0001.jpg**"

im using the script:

```
#/bin/zsh
for f in "$@"
do
    filedate=$(mdls $f | grep kMDItemContentCreationDate -m 1 | awk '{print $3, $4}');
    filename=$f:t
    filepath=$f:h
    mv $filepath/{"$filename","$filedate $filename"}
done
```

Can i somehow just add +0200 or +0100 to the "filedate...$4" and how?(and then manually order when the number of houser in the name is over 24) or is there a smarter way to ad time zone designator(TZD) to the script? I have not used script before so im completely new to all this. Hopw someone can help me.

Comment: Just a 'by the way'… your time format 20/22/30 will cause huge problems for Windows users if they ever get the file You should use something platform agnostic, like 20.22.30 or 20-22-30 See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names for characters you should avoid in filenames.

Comment: thanks for the hint, actually im deleteting the "/" with another automator action so it just "2020-06-30 202230 IMG_0001.jpg" for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

To change UTC time to reflect your timezone, run the output of `mdls` thru the `date` command. You can also format the output of the date command.

```
utcfiledate=$( mdls -n kMDItemContentCreationDate -raw  FILE)

date -f '%F %T %z' -j "$utcfiledate" '+%F %T'
```

To remove the colons from the output

```
date -f '%F %T %z' -j "$utcfiledate" '+%F %H%M%S'
```